# IBM Connections - Environment Sync up

Tags: connection, ibm-connections

We have 1 Dev, 1 QA and 1 Prod environments with IBM Connections 3.0.1. Our Lower environments i.e. Dev and QA has gone out of sync, wrt to Production. This has resulted in fixes working on lower environments not working on Production.

We would like to base line both the lower environments visa-vi the Production.
The env's are virtualised, and restoring snapshots of Prod env to other env has been ruled out by the IS and Network team. Would need either some manual / script based solutions to do the same.

Can somebody help me in identifying the activities that needs to be done along with the best practices to be followed, in order for all the environments to be same [ as that of production ]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to create a new dev and QA environment from scratch and patch them to the same level as production. After testing. Apply all your customizations. Test again.